# Can dimensions in Apache Druid be considered as a form of primary key?

Tags: database, time-series, druid

In other word, in Druid, if rollup is disabled, will metric values with the same timestamp and dimension(value) overwrite former metric value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight answer is: No, it does not behave like a key.

Druid uses immutable files called segments, which contain millions of rows each in a columnar format. While ingestion with perfect rollup will create individual rows that are a unique combination of __time and dimensions, this is not true in general.

You can update data in Druid through the use of combining ingestion, here is a [great blog on the subject](https://blog.hellmar-becker.de/2023/03/07/selective-bulk-upserts-in-apache-druid/). You can also use [REPLACE statements in SQL](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/multi-stage-query/examples.html#replace-for-replacing-a-specific-time-segment) in the same fashion to achieve this.

For streaming ingestion with data updates, there are query approaches to getting the latest value of each column ( [blog post on that](https://imply.io/blog/upserts-and-data-deduplication-with-druid/) ) .

Comment: Thank you, I have read all posts you mentioned but still confused about this: WHAT is data **logically identified** by ? Since I saw all places concerning the key (replacement, upsert...) are handled by somehow workaround, like filter and re-index ,etc., and no direct answer about the logical identification of a tuple/record within a data source.

Comment: Or, is there nothing acting like a primary key ? As Druid doesn't apply primary key constraint ?

Comment: There is no primary key. The design is for fast aggregation and filtering needed for OLAP workloads on event data.